# Determine the bounding rect of a WPF element relative to some parent

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, bounds, rect

I consider this a pretty simple request, but I can't seem to find a conclusive answer in my searches. How can I determine the bounds of a particular visual element in my window, relative to some other parent element?

I've tried using `LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot` but this just seems to return a `Rect` at 0,0 and doesn't reflect the actual location of the element.

What I'm trying to do is take a "screenshot" of a window using `RenderTargetBitmap` and then crop it to a particular element, but I can't get the element's bounds to know what to crop the bitmap to!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is quite simple:

```
public static Rect BoundsRelativeTo(this FrameworkElement element,
                                         Visual relativeTo)
{
  return
    element.TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
           .TransformBounds(LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(element));
}
```

In fact it may be overkill to put it in a separate method.

Comment: `GetLayoutSlot` gets the space that's allocated in the layout for the element, but the actual element size could be different if it has an explicit width/height and/or a transform. To get the "true" size rect, try `element.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(element.RenderSize))`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, see Mauro Sampletro's or DanW's answer below which does work.

Answer (score 9):

The LayoutSlot option didn't work for me at all.
This ended up giving me a child position relative to a specified parent/ancestor control:

```
    public static Rect BoundsRelativeTo(this FrameworkElement child, Visual parent)
    {
        GeneralTransform gt = child.TransformToAncestor(parent);
        return gt.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, child.ActualWidth, child.ActualHeight));
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, the accepted answer did not. Working with a Border in a Grid with WPF in .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account a few suggestions i found here this solved the problem for me.

```
item.TransformToVisual( relativeToElement )
    .TransformBounds( new Rect( item.RenderSize ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I finally managed to figure it out using a combination of `LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot()` (although I probably could have used either `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` or `RenderSize`) and `UIElement.TranslatePoint()`.

Seems a rather complicated solution when it could be as simple as this:

```
myElement.GetBounds( relativeElement );
```

Oh well. Maybe time for an extension method. :)

Comment: I was saying there should be.

Comment: Would you please show the complete solution? I didn't get it to work. It was always wrong relative to some parent element. For now, I'm converting everything to screen coordinates with `myElement.PointToScreen(new Point())` which is okay for handling WM_NCHITTEST. But I still consider it a hack.

Comment: We all are happy that you solved your problem. Please provide us your solution here.

Comment: @Nasenbaer Sorry I haven't done .NET development in some time. I suggest reading the documentation for `TranslatePoint`.